# Faster way to find out if a number starts with 2?

Tags: java, performance, numbers

In Java - what is the faster way to find if the given integer number is starting with the digit 2 without having to convert the number into a string?

```
String.valueOf(number).charAt(0) == '2'
```

Comment: Is the number an integer? a double?

Comment: You are not using `substring` in your sample. Do you mean avoiding conversion to string?

Comment: @user2652406 - The OP is *>>you<<* ... the original poster.  The thing you are proposing to edit is ... the Question.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers - there are three different methods so far in the answers and I tested those using JUnit Benchmak and the one using divide wins.

Comment: I added the code from OldCurmudgeon and it beats the divide by method from Jon Skeet! Look at my answer for the code and results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you wanted to avoid converting it to a string, you could just keep dividing by 10 to find the most significant digit:

```
int getMostSignificantDigit(int x)
{
    // Need to handle Integer.MIN_VALUE "specially" as the absolute value can't
    // represented. We can hard-code the fact that it starts with 2 :)
    x = x == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? 2 : Math.abs(x);
    while (x >= 10)
    {
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I don't know whether this would be faster than Husman's log/pow approach.

Comment: not sure if faster, but certainly easier to grasp :D Anyway, +1 for both.

Comment: You can just get the absolute value of the integer before you start, to ensure it is positive.

Comment: @Husman: I considered that, but you'd need to take `Integer.MIN_VALUE` into account. Basically it ends up being sufficiently icky that I didn't want to get into it ;)

Comment: Note that JDK's implementation of `Integer.toString` is already highly optimized.

Comment: while (x > 10) should be while (x >= 10), to avoid returning 10 when x=10. (Stack overflow wont let me edit the code, as my edit isnt 6 chars or more)

Comment: I tested the different solutions (see my answer) and this one is the fastest :)

Answer (score 9):

I've pitted the various solutions against each other:

```
public class FirstDigit
{
  static int digit;
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public void string() {
    for (int i = 200_000_000; i < 400_000_000; i += 999961)
      digit = Integer.toString(i).charAt(0);
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public void math() {
    for (int i = 200_000_000; i < 400_000_000; i += 999961) {
      digit = (int) floor(i / pow(10, floor(log10(i))));
    }
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public void divide() {
    for (int i = 200_000_000; i < 400_000_000; i += 999961) {
      int x = i;
      while (x > 10) x /= 10;
      digit = x;
    }
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public void brokenDivide() {
    for (int i = 200_000_000; i < 400_000_000; i += 999961) {
      int x = i;
      while (x > 10) x >>= 3;
      digit = x;
    }
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public void bitTwiddling() {
    for (int i = 200_000_000; i < 400_000_000; i += 999961) {
      digit = i/powersOf10[log10(i)];
    }
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public boolean avoidDivide() {
    boolean b = true;
    for (int i = 200_000_000; i < 400_000_000; i += 999961) {
      b ^= firstDigitIsTwo(i);
    }
    return b;
  }


  private static final int[] log256 = new int[256];
  static {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) log256[i] = 1 + log256[i / 2];
    log256[0] = -1;
  }
  private static int powersOf10[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10_000, 100_000,
    1_000_000, 10_000_000, 100_000_000, 1_000_000_000};

  public static int log2(int v) {
    int t, tt;
    return ((tt = v >> 16) != 0)?
        (t = tt >> 8) != 0 ? 24 + log256[t] : 16 + log256[tt]
      : (t = v >> 8) != 0 ? 8 + log256[t] : log256[v];
  }
  public static int log10(int v) {
    int t = (log2(v) + 1) * 1233 >> 12;
    return t - (v < powersOf10[t] ? 1 : 0);
  }

  static final int [] limits = new int[] {
    2_000_000_000, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
    200_000_000, 300_000_000-1,
    20_000_000, 30_000_000-1,
    2_000_000, 3_000_000-1,
    200_000, 300_000-1,
    20_000, 30_000-1,
    2000, 3000-1,
    200, 300-1,
    20, 30-1,
    2, 3-1,
  };
  public static boolean firstDigitIsTwo(int v) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < limits.length; i+= 2) {
      if ( v > limits[i+1] ) return false;
      if ( v >= limits[i] ) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark                   Mode Thr    Cnt  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
FirstDigit.avoidDivide     thrpt   1      3    5     2324.271       58.145 ops/msec
FirstDigit.bitTwiddling    thrpt   1      3    5      716.453        6.407 ops/msec
FirstDigit.brokenDivide    thrpt   1      3    5      578.259        7.534 ops/msec
o.s.FirstDigit.divide      thrpt   1      3    5      125.509        2.323 ops/msec
o.s.FirstDigit.string      thrpt   1      3    5       78.233        2.030 ops/msec
o.s.FirstDigit.math        thrpt   1      3    5       14.226        0.034 ops/msec
```

- the `math` approach is a clear loser;
- the `string` approach beats `math` by a factor of six;
- the simplest `divide` algorithm is 60% faster than that;
- OldCurmudgeon's `bitTwiddling` algorithm is yet another six times faster than `divide`;
- OldCurmudgeon's special-cased `avoidDivide` approach (which gives a yes/no answer directly, unlike all others, which actually determine the first digit) is another three times faster than the `bitTwiddiling` algo and is the undisputed winner;
- for diagnostic I have also included a `brokenDivide` algo. Instead of dividing by ten, it just shifts by three, giving the wrong answer. The point is to underline where the bottleneck with the `divide` algorithm is: `brokenDivide` is 4.6 times faster than `divide`, and just 0.2 times slower than `bitTwiddling`.

Note that I have used quite large numbers; the relative speeds vary with the magnitude.

Comment: Maybe use shift operator instead of pow. Will be a little faster. :)

Comment: I should, yes. @assylias

Comment: @SajalDutta - how do you propose to calculate 10^N using shifting?

Comment: @StephenC Oops..didn't see the integer limit..my bad.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Could you perhaps see how [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069079/823393) performs? I suspect it will not be as good as my first post but it may turn out to be quite quick.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon It is a *screamer*! It beat bit twiddling threefold! I also tested a "broken division" algo: same as Jon's but instead of `/= 10` I do `>>= 3`. It speeds it up dramatically, bringing it almost on a par with bit twiddling. Yes, division is the main operation to avoid for performance.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Wow!! I didn't expect that improvement! Thank you for your work.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon There's one thing: the way you've put together the array, it favors large numbers, and I'm testing with large numbers. If it were reversed, it may get just a bit slower for the same number range.

Answer (score 8):

I would be tempted to do something like this:

```
  x = Math.abs(x);
  if ( ((int) Math.floor(x / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(x))))) == 2 )
  {
     ... // x equals 2
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Derived from [Bit Twiddling Hacks By Sean Eron Anderson](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

```
/*
 * Log(2) of an int.
 * 
 * See: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup
 */
private static final int[] Log256 = new int[256];

static {
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    Log256[i] = 1 + Log256[i / 2];
  }
  Log256[0] = -1;
}

public static int log2(int v) {
  int t, tt;
  if ((tt = v >> 16) != 0) {
    return (t = tt >> 8) != 0 ? 24 + Log256[t] : 16 + Log256[tt];
  } else {
    return = (t = v >> 8) != 0 ? 8 + Log256[t] : Log256[v];
  }
}

/*
 * Log(10) of an int.
 * 
 * See: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10
 */
private static int PowersOf10[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000,
                                   1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};

public static int log10(int v) {
  int t = (log2(v) + 1) * 1233 >> 12;
  return t - (v < PowersOf10[t] ? 1 : 0);
}

// Returns the top digit of the integer.
public static int topDigit(int n) {
  return n / PowersOf10[log10(n)];
}
```

I've tested this and it seems to work - how does it benchmark?

Comment: It's actually about 5 times faster than Jon Skeet's solution. Although it looks much more complex, it's easy to forget how slow branching (e.g. a while loop) can be on a modern CPU.

Comment: @jarnbjo - It certainly **should** be faster but whether it is or not depends on benchmarks. I look forward to Arnauld's feedback.

Comment: You should add `+1` to the result of your `log10()` method.

Comment: This is ingenius, deserves to be printed and framed on my wall. Excellent work.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - Are you sure? I have tried to match the original as far as possible. My tests, although not rigorous, seem to produce the correct top digit.

Comment: @Husman - Thanks but it is not my own work (apart from translation from C to Java) - please see the reference I posted at the start.

Comment: @Arnaud: No, adding 1 would give the wrong result. The log10 method rounds down ([0,9] -> 0, [10,99] -> 1 etc.) which is necessary to use the result as a lookup index in the 0-based array to find the divisor.

Comment: This `log10()` method has a very weird behavior. Can you test? On my computer, I have those strange result `log10(100)` returns `0` (should return `2`). `log10(1000)` returns `2` (should return `3`).

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - On my PC I get:
`log10(100) = 2
log10(1000) = 3`
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Arnaud's benchmark gives Jon Skeet's approach an unfair advantage, so your algo turns out just a bit faster than his. If you look at my results, you'll see that for 9-digit numbers your algo is as much as six times faster than the naïve division algo. Division is expensive and your algo uses only one.

Comment: Minor points: the line `Log256[0] = Log256[1] = 0;` is redundant; you can just delete it. In `log2` you don't really need the `r` variable, that's just C-style single-exit-point programming. In `log10`, likewise, it is unusual to split variable declaration and initialization.

Comment: @jarnbjo Actually, I bet on the division as the main drag in Jon Skeet's approach. Branching can't be *that* expensive, especially when the JIT compiler inserts the appropriate speculative branch instruction. Also note that OldCurmudgeoen's solution has no less than three branch points.

Comment: @Marko: My statement was perhaps too brief. What I meant is that *conditional* branches are very slow, at least if the condition is such that the CPU's branch prediction does not work very well. If the input is randomly distributed across the valid range of an int, all conditional branches in this answer mostly go the same way, so that the branch prediction will probably work in most cases. Jon's division loop has a much higher variation in the outcome of the branch condition, making it less likely that the branch prediction succeeds.

Comment: @jarnbjo The outcomes in the `log2` and `log10` method are, as far as I can see, all equally likely given a random int. And consider Jon Skeet's example, one outcome means another division, the other a simple return. So a speculative branch towards another division is virtually free---either it guessed right, or there is no more work to do. Quite the opposite happens in OldCurmudgeon's `log2`, where each branch means a different calculation.

Comment: @marko: If the int is random, the result of log2 will in 255 out of 256 cases be 24 + Log256[t].

Comment: @jarnbjo Although such uniform distribution is unrealistic in practice, you are absolutely right :) But if we apply the same logic to Jon's case, then in 9 cases out of 10 there will be an equal number of iterations.

Comment: @marko: No, there will not be the same number of iterations in 9 out of 10 cases. Since the range of a (positive) int goes from 0 to just over 2 billion, there is only a 53% chance for the number to have 10 digits and 42% chance for 9 digits. Even if the loop always had the same number of iterations, I doubt that any CPU's branch prediction is clever enough to know that  every 10th or 9th branch goes in the less likely direction.

Comment: @jarnbjo But the main point is that 9 out of 10 branch predictions will be right. Do you really think that 1 failed prediction after 9 successful ones can account for a sixfold performance drop?

Comment: @marko: No, the failed branch prediction is itself not the only reason for the performance drop. On my computer, I benchmark a division to 4.5 CPU cycles. I can't think of an easy way to reliably benchmark a failed branch prediction, but I wouldn't find it unlikely that it took some 20 cycles or more. For your tests, you can e.g. replace /= 10 with >>= 3 in Jon's answer. The result will be wrong, but you can probably see that even without the divisions, his code is still much slower than this solutions.

Comment: @jarnbjo The results are in: replacing `/= 10` with `>>= 3` gave the "divide" algo a *tremedous* boost and brought it almost on a par with bit twiddling. Division is the clear bottleneck. (see the results for "brokenDivide" in my answer.)

Comment: @marko: I am getting quite different results than your benchmark, but two different CPU models may of course behave very differently on such specific benchmarks. Do I interpret your results correctly than the bitTwiddling method takes only 1.4ns on average? I find that hard to believe, or are you running the tests simultaneously on multiple cores, so that the runtime of each method is actually 1.4*nCores ns?

Comment: @jarnbjo No, I,ve got 716 ops/msec, and each op is about 200 calculations (the loop from 200,000,000 to 400,000,000, step 999,961). That's some 143,000 calculations/msec, or 7 ns per single calculation. On a 2.4 GHz CPU core, that's some 20 CPU cycles. And that's all subject to my interpretation of `jmh`'s output.

Comment: @jarnbjo Note also that I don't have `bitTwiddling` as a separate function, I do the top-level calculation inline. That may account for some small advantage.

Comment: @jarnbjo If you want to get to the bottom of this, I can send you my code. It will give you a chance to scrutinize my work, compare the results with your platform, and have `jmh` ready for future µbenchmarks. It's maven-based, so all you'll have to run is `mvn package` and `java -jar target/microbenchmarks.jar '.*'`

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED** : I now test with a different number on each iteration and I added OldCurmudgeon's solution (the one derived from Bit Twiddling Hacks By Sean Eron Anderson).

I benchmarked different solutions, including Jon Skeet's :) :

Here is my main method used for this test:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  long tip = System.currentTimeMillis();

  //Call the test method 10 000 000 times.
  for(int i= 0 ; i< 10_000_000 ; i++){
    //Here I call the method representing the algorithm.
    foo3(i);
  }

  long top = System.currentTimeMillis();

  System.out.println("Total time : "+(top-tip));

}
```

**1)** With the OP's solution :

```
public static boolean foo1(Integer i){
  return String.valueOf(i).charAt(0) == '2';
}
```

It takes **425 ms** on my computer.

**2)** Try with Integer.toString().startsWith() :

```
public static boolean foo2(Integer i){
  return Integer.toString(i).startsWith("2");
}
```

It takes **410 ms** on my computer.

**3)** With Husman's solution :

```
public static boolean foo3(Integer i){
  i = Math.abs(i);
  return ((int) Math.floor(i / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(i))))) == 2;
}
```

It takes **2020 ms**.

**4)** With Jon's solution :

```
public static boolean foo4(Integer i){
  return getMostSignificantDigit(i)==2;
}

public static int getMostSignificantDigit(int x)
{
  // TODO: Negative numbers :)
  while (x > 10)
  {
    x = x / 10;
  }
  return x;
}
```

It takes **125 ms**

**5)** With OldCurmudgeon's solution (see her answer):

```
public static boolean foo5(Integer i){
  return OldCurmudgeon.topDigit(i)==2;
}
```

It takes **97 ms**

Comment: Your benchmark has some flaws (no warm-up, result of the method is discarded...) so it is difficult to tell if the results are reliable

Comment: The benchmark would be more useful if you would not test the algorithm for a single number only!

Comment: I would be more interested in seeing the method called with different parameters, i.e. 999999 and decremented by 1 or so to see what they all perform like under load. Although the division (aka Jon Skeet) method looks like a sure winner.

Comment: @assylias What do you mean by warm-up? I tried each test 10 times and gave the mean result for each. Is that enough?
@Husman : I replaced `foo(23456)` with `foo(i)` (the `for` variable). The result are nearly the same, except for Jon's method which becomes even faster.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle The foo method will be compiled during your measurement. That can bias the results. It is better to first run the method 10 or 15 thousand times to get it to compile, then run the actual test. My second note was that when you just run `foo()` in your loop, because the method has no side effect, the compiler might realise it and completely optimise the method away (i.e. treat it as a no-op). It happens that your results are in line with Marko's so all is fine.

Comment: @assylias Well, his results make Jon's solution stand out much too strongly compared to my results: 7 times faster vs. just 60% faster. He used `startsWith` instead of `charAt`, don't know how much that matters.

Comment: I just tried. `String.startsWith()` is slightly more efficient. I get ~360s with the OP's solution. Another difference is that I use `Integer.toString()` where as the OP uses `String.valueOf()`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - Any chance of adding [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18054857/823393) to your benchmark? I would be interested in the results.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon : I had to modify your `log10` method (had to add +1). Apart from this, your method seems significantly faster. I updated the benchmark.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle can you show the change you did to log10 method?

Comment: `return t - (v < PowersOf10[t] ? 1 : 0);` => `return 1 + t - (v < PowersOf10[t] ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: @Arnaud: Since the run time of Jon's method depends on the size of the input parameter, testing with small ints (<10000000) gives it an advantage in the benchmark compared to testing with an evenly distributed random data set.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle On my computer, with the original OldCurmudgeon's code: `System.out.format("%d %d %d", log10(10), log10(100), log10(1000));` Output: `1 2 3`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I agree with Marko Topolnik - there is no need for +1 in log10 method from OldCurmudgeon's post.

Comment: I totally agree with the mathematical result, no problem with that. But for a reason I don't understand, `log10(10)` does not return `1` on my computer but the problem seems to be on my side.

Answer (score 4):

One more possibility - because division is clearly a bottleneck (or is it?):

```
// Pairs of range limits.
// Reverse order to put the widest range at the top.
static final int [] limits = new int[] {
  // Can hard-code this one to avoid one comparison.
  //2000000000, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
  200000000, 300000000-1,
  20000000, 30000000-1,
  2000000, 3000000-1,
  200000, 300000-1,
  20000, 30000-1,
  2000, 3000-1,
  200, 300-1,
  20, 30-1,
  2, 3-1,
};

public static boolean firstDigitIsTwo(int v) {
  // All ints from there up start with 2.
  if ( v >= 2000000000 ) return true;
  for ( int i = 0; i < limits.length; i += 2 ) {
    // Assumes array is decreasing order.
    if ( v > limits[i+1] ) return false;
    // In range?
    if ( v >= limits[i] ) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: [Marko's benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18054242/823393) suggest that this one is the fastest of all and is dramatically faster than even I expected.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering here just so I can post the test code and results:

```
public class NumberStart extends AbstractBenchmark {

private static final int START = 10000000;
private static final int END = 50000000;

private static int result;

@Test
@BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 1, warmupRounds = 1)
public void divide() {
    for (int x = START; x < END; x++) {
        int i = x;
        while (i > 10) {
            i = i / 10;
        }
        result = i;
    }
}

@Test
@BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 1, warmupRounds = 1)
public void math() {
    for (int x = START; x < END; x++) {
        result = (int) Math.floor(x / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(x))));
    }
}

@Test
@BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 1, warmupRounds = 1)
public void string() {
    for (int x = START; x < END; x++) {
        result = (int) Integer.toString(x).charAt(0);
    }
}

@Test
@BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 1, warmupRounds = 1)
public void bitmath() {
    for (int x = START; x < END; x++) {
        result = (int) BitMath.topDigit(x);
    }
}
}
```

`bitmath()` method uses the code posted by OldCurmudgeon.

And here are the results:

```
NumberStart.divide: [measured 1 out of 2 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
 round: 0.36 [+- 0.00], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 0, GC.time: 0.00, time.total: 0.71, time.warmup: 0.36, time.bench: 0.35
NumberStart.string: [measured 1 out of 2 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
 round: 1.64 [+- 0.00], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 147, GC.time: 0.08, time.total: 3.31, time.warmup: 1.68, time.bench: 1.64
NumberStart.bitmath: [measured 1 out of 2 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
 round: 0.22 [+- 0.00], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 0, GC.time: 0.00, time.total: 0.45, time.warmup: 0.23, time.bench: 0.22
NumberStart.math: [measured 1 out of 2 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
 round: 4.93 [+- 0.00], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 0, GC.time: 0.00, time.total: 9.89, time.warmup: 4.95, time.bench: 4.93
```

`bitmath()` method is the fastest method so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int intValue=213;
    if(String.valueOf(intValue).startsWith("2"))
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the question: **without having to convert the number into a string** ?

Comment: hmm, question is edited, I just considered not to use substring.

Answer (score 0):

`((int) number / 10^(numberlength-1))`  will give first digit.

Comment: In order to obtain numberlength, you will either need to convert the number to a String (equivalent to the OP's solution) or using a log10 (equivalent to Husman's solution).